# How to code a JS function that opens a website when HTML buttons entered correctlty

Tags: javascript, html

I need help in 2 functions for the following HTML / JS file.
The first function (myFunction2) needs to open a url when code is entered correctly
or make the font red and delete the whole code.
the second function (myFunction3) needs to act like a delete button, it should delete the last number entered

If possible i am also trying to find out how to set a maximum for characters entered

Thank you very much !

```
<html>
<body>

    <p class="Header"> Code: </p> 
    <input type="text" id="field2" class="field2"><br><br>
<div class="Tasten">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=1 onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=2 onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=3 onclick="myFunction(this)"><br>
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=4 onclick="myFunction(this)"> 
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=5 onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=6 onclick="myFunction(this)"><br>
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=7 onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=8 onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=9 onclick="myFunction(this)"><br>
  <input class="calculator0" type="button" id="field1" value="0" onclick="myFunction(this)">
</div>
  <input class="Back" type="button" id="OK" value="<-" onclick="myFunction3()">
  <input class="Enter" type="button" id="OK" value="OK" onclick="myFunction2()">




<script>


function myFunction(button) {
  document.getElementById("field2").value += button.value;
}

function myFunction2() {

    if (document.getElementById("field2").value === 1101){
        /*---> Navigate to another website*/
    }
else{
  /* ---> Turn Font in id"field2" to red and reset the text field */
}}
function myFunction3(){
 /* ---> delete the last number */
}


</script>
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

Here I added a condition that displays an `alert` when receiving a string of more than 10 characters.

myFunction2: since the input produces a `string`, a conversion is made to a `number` type. If the condition matches, then the page opens and goes to: https://www.google.com.

myFunction3: the input field is reset to empty and the color becomes the default.

```
<html>
<body>

    <p class="Header"> Code: </p> 
    <input type="text" id="field2" class="field2"><br><br>
<div class="Tasten">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=1 onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=2 onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=3 onclick="myFunction(this)"><br>
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=4 onclick="myFunction(this)"> 
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=5 onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=6 onclick="myFunction(this)"><br>
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=7 onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=8 onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <input class="calculator" type="button" id="field1" value=9 onclick="myFunction(this)"><br>
  <input class="calculator0" type="button" id="field1" value="0" onclick="myFunction(this)">
</div>
  <input class="Back" type="button" id="OK" value="<-" onclick="myFunction3()">
  <input class="Enter" type="button" id="OK" value="OK" onclick="myFunction2()">
</body>



<script>


function myFunction(button) {
  lol = document.getElementById("field2").value += button.value;
}

function myFunction2() {
    if (document.getElementById("field2").value.length > 10){
    window.alert("maximum number of characters exceeded");
    
    }

    if (Number(document.getElementById("field2").value) === 1101){
        /*---> Navigate to another website*/
        window.open('https://www.google.com');
    }
else{
  /* ---> Turn Font in id"field2" to red and reset the text field */
  document.getElementById("field2").style.color = "red";
  document.body.style.color = "red";
}}
function myFunction3(){
 /* ---> delete the last number */
 document.getElementById("field2").value = "";
 document.getElementById("field2").style.color = "";
 document.body.style.color = "";
}


</script>
```